# MongoDB combining find with text search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongojs

I'm trying to filter a MongoDB collection with a `.find()` query and run a text search on the results to lower the cost of the query but I can't seem to be able to chain the commands.

Here's what I've tried (that doesn't work):

```
db.jobs.find({
    "salary.max": {
        $gte: 50000,
        $lte: 120000
    }
}).runCommand("text", {
    search: "metal"
})
```

I've also tried the query in the reverse order, which defeats the purpose and doesn't work either.

Is there a way to chain a `.runCommand()` to a `.find()` in MongoDB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the .`find` function returns a `DBCursor` which hasn't got a a `.runCommand`-function. So this obviously doesn't work.

But what does work is using your find-query in the `text` database command. As you can read in [the documentation for text searching](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/#dbcmd.text), you can pass a `filter`as an optional parameter to the text command. These filter documents work exactly like those you pass to `find`.

```
db.jobs.runCommand( "text", { 
    search: "metal",
    filter: { 
        "salary.max": {
            $gte: 50000,
            $lte: 120000
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Can you also chain a location based query (2dsphere) to this?

Comment: @A.M.K I see no reason why it should not work. The geospatial operators like `$nearSphere` or `$geoWithin` are normal filter-operators, so you can add them to your filter document. And while the documentation points out that each collection can only have *one text index* and *one geo index*, it doesn't say anywhere that it can't have one of each.

Comment: OK, thank you. While I waited for an answer I played around with ElasticSearch a little and it looks like the extra coding trouble of switching will be worth it.

Comment: Why the hell is any of this necessary? Why isn't text search part of find()?

Comment: @light24bulbs I saw that you commented on this. I've since found that MongoDB is a fantastic database engine but it simply isn't made for searching.

Elasticsearch takes a bit (a lot?) of time to setup but it's well worth it.

Comment: This seems to be deprecated in 2.6.